# Quit powershell in jupyter terminal

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, jupyter-notebook

How to quit PowerShell in the jupyter terminal and get back to `>>>` (python interpreter)?

Tried calling quit() in the terminal didn't work. I guess it has to do something with the env variable.
But unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```bash
exit(keep_kernel=True)
```

Obtained from this [github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/48#issuecomment-169708600)

---

**Update**

Just typing in **exit** worked for me -

[image]

Comment: have you opened the terminal in the browser?

Comment: try only **exit**

Comment: plz share the screenshot of what happens when you type in exit, in your question

Answer (score 0):

Type `exit` and you'll see that the terminal outputs `[CLOSED]` but it doesn't actually exit out of the terminal screen.
Click on Jupyter icon on top left corner and once you check the running terminals there you'll see that the terminal is already closed.